# how to truncate a float to a either an int or no fractional bit

Tags: swift

I have a float that we'd like to truncate the fractional part off of but not sure the easiest way to do this. Just picking up Swift and most of the thoughts seemed way too involved. Currently I have:

```
details.details.append((titles[2], "\(averageAnnualSolarProduction) kW"))
```

but this is giving me a fraction which I want removed.

Comment: What is `details`?  What is `details.details`?  I assume `averageAnnualSolarProduction` is a `Float`, but you want the string to not include the fractional part?

Comment: exactly re it be a float. not sure what details.details is to be honest. Just have to get this fixed for other dev.

Comment: Do you want it to round or just lob off the decimal?

Comment: you can just cut it off / truncate it. thx for help

Comment: let myFloat = 3.5; let myFloatTruncated = Int(myFloat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to combine two things:

1. `String`'s `format:` initializer
2. `floor` operation which will make sure our decimal number doesn't round up.

If we want to keep these operations in-line, we'd want something that looks like this:

```
details.details.append((titles[2], String(format: "%.0f kW", floor(averageAnnualSolarProduction))))
```

But that's a lot of parenthesis.  Looks a little better if we unnest this a bit.

```
let solarProduction = String(format: "%.0f kW", floor(averageAnnualSolarProduction))
details.details.append((titles[2], solarProduction))
```

For clarity here, `floor` takes a number like `3.89` and returns the largest integer number smaller than what was passed in, so it would return `3.0` here.

And to be sure that we're not printing the `.0`, we use `String`'s `format:` initializer, which takes a format string and arguments.  This works just like format strings have worked since at least C.  `%f` specifies our argument is a floating point number, and the `.0` specifies that we will display zero numbers after the decimal point.

If we're find with rounding up, we can drop the call to `floor` and simply use the `format:` initializer, but for a value of `3.89`, this would give us a string that looks like `"4 kW"`.