# Swift ios 10 digit unix timestamp

Tags: swift, timestamp

I wonder how I can create a 10 digit unix timestamp

```
NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
```

will print: **1478638179.2932**

I would like to only print:

**1478638179**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to truncate a float to a either an int or no fractional bit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30202514/how-to-truncate-a-float-to-a-either-an-int-or-no-fractional-bit)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You mean you just want the integral part of the value?

```
let seconds = Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)
```